# Running a protractor.js test from a inquirer.js menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I'm stuck in a problem. I have a set of end to end tests written with protractor.js and I made a little menu with inquire.js in which I'll select which tests I would like to run. The problem is, I really can't find any information on how to actually link those two projects together so the menu can call a test once selected. Here is a sample of a test and the menu I made:

This is my protractor test:

```
var session = require('../login.js');

describe('The customer view', function() {

    var physicalPersonRegistration = {};

    physicalPersonRegistration.loginTest = function() {

        it('should Login', function() {
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

            browser.get('http://localhost:8080/project');

            session.username.sendKeys('admin');
            session.password.sendKeys('admin');
            session.submit.click();

            browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        });
    };

    //executing tests
    physicalPersonRegistration.loginTest();
});
```

And this is my inquire.js menu:

```
  var inquirer = require("inquirer");

  var questions = [

        {
          type: "list",
          name: "tests",
          message: "Which test do you wish to run?",
          choices: [
            "Login Test",
            "Run all Tests"
          ]
        },

    ];

    inquirer.prompt(questions, function(answers) {
      console.log(answers);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to determine what DOM elements you want to interact with.  You can start by using the [protractor element explorer](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/debugging). Use that to determine the kinds of locators to use. And then build your test around interacting with the browser.